# What does [E, ]**F mean?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

From `dict.update()` docstring:

```
D.update([E, ]**F) -> None.  Update D from dict/iterable E and F.
```

what does the `[E, ]**F` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update` can accept an existing dict (or iterable of key/value pairs) as its optional positional argument `[E, ]`, as well as additional explicit key/value pairs as keyword arguments `**F`.

For example:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> e = {'b': 2}
>>> d.update(e, c=3)  # dict positional argument
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> d.update([('d', 4), ('e', 5)], f=6)  # iterable positional argument
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
>>> d.update(g=7)  # no positional argument
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7}
```

Comment: Can you please break down each part and tell me how you read it? What does the [] tell you, what does the , tell you, the **, etc.

Comment: `[E,]` means `E` (and the comma to separate it from any following keyword arguments) is optional, `**F` indicates zero or more keyword arguments. The letters themselves don't really mean anything. `d.update(e,)` is legal, though rarely written. `d.update(,c=3)`, with a leading comma, is *not* legal, which is why the comma is inside the `[...]` with the `E`.

Comment: It would mean the comma is required even if `E` were omitted, but that's not legal Python syntax.

Comment: Do you think this signature is actually documented incorrectly since [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/)?

Comment: Do you mean, should it be something like `D.update(E=None, / **F)`? Possibly. The docstring is just using an informal ABNF-like notation right now.